# How to format a string received as input using named tokens instead of numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting

The standard way of formatting strings takes numbered tokens ie: `{0}` but I would like to be able to format using tokens that contain meaningful names like `{id}`

I know about string interpolation, but in my case the string to format comes as an input, so the named tokens won't reference members at compile time. Is there a way to do this, perhaps using a dictionary of token names and values?

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820331/how-to-extract-a-dynamic-object-from-a-variable-template-string-and-merge-it-in) which talks about dynamic objects, except this case involves the code providing the template and the user providing the values for the tokens, but in my case it's the opposite.

The user provides a template containing tokens with predefined names. My code takes the template and inserts the right values where there are tokens.

Comment: Something like this: [How to extract a dynamic object from a variable template string and merge it in again?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64822266/7444103)?

Comment: I looked at it and this is not what I am looking for. Updated to question going in more detail.